# Which application context set in IntelliJ IDEA for Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, liferay

So far I run Tomcat server (v. 7.0.26) in windows command by `catalina.bat start` script. If I want to deploy my web app I have to build it by Maven and copy WARs to specify Tomcat deploy directory. When server start everything is ok.

Now I try to connect my web app to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.4. My app have multiple WARs. At `Run/Debug Configuration` I add new Tomcat Server. At the `Deployment` tab I have:

[image: deployment tab]

I have to choose `Application context` but if I set blank for more than one artifact I get error `Duplicate context path''`. Same situation is when I choose `/`. If I try to run server nothing deploy. Which application context I should set?

Answer (score 3):

The application context will be part of the URL you have to enter in your browser when accessing the application. You could use the name of your war file:

```
kb-hook
```

Then you can enter the adress in your browser and find the application. (Given your Tomcat runs on port 8080) You will maybe have to add a path to a resource within the war behind that URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/kb-hook/
```

You could also choose another name, but the name of the war file is chosen quite often.

Comment: But I if run standalone Tomcat server (outside of IntelliJ) I can get to my app without any context: `http://localhost:8080/`. Why I need to add custom context in IntelliJ?

Comment: Just set it to `/`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I can't set context `/` form more than one WAR.

Comment: That is because app server cannot deploy multiple web applications under the same context.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, so whhich application context set if my app have multiple WARs?

Comment: Use different contexts for multiple web applications.

Comment: @CrazyCoder But here I have one web appluacation with multiple WARs.

Comment: Then make a single web app in one .war file and deploy it instead of 3 different web applications.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  I can't change project structure, it is independet of me. Is it realy no way to have one web app with multiple WARs to deploy by IntelliJ?

Comment: It's not an IDE limitation, multiple .war files cannot be deployed under the same context.

Comment: @CrazyCoder So I will come back to my previous question: why if I run my app in outside Tomcat (not by IntelliJ) i don't have to set any context and everything is ok?

Comment: Because your app is deployed under multiple contexts (by the names of the .war files).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Ok, so where can I find default contexts which is used for my WARs?

Comment: @CrazyCoder In my Tomcat I have `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` with `path=""` and I don't have `context.xml` files in my specific WARs. So default context `""` is global for my Tomcat? For which WAR i should set it?

Comment: For WAR files the default context would be the war file name.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple war files to IDEA deployment?