# Is it possible to add multiple war files to deployment for run/debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, configuration

I try to debug my web app by IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. **My app have multiple WARs**. At Run/Debug Configuration I add new Tomcat Server. At the Deployment tab I have:

If I add more than one WAR artifact I get error **Duplicate context path '/'**.

Question for this context is not answered here for a long time: [Which application context set in IntelliJ IDEA for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633560/which-application-context-set-in-intellij-idea-for-tomcat)

So, let's clear: **Is it possible to add multiple war files to deployment for run/debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA?**

Answer (score 0):

You Must add each WAR file in separate tomcat server that created in servers in Intellij IDEA and set a different port for each one.
After that run both of them.

Comment: Thank you.
How can I debug applications from different war files if they should use common port?

Comment: For debug must set a different port for each server and attach to both of them at the same time.